# Send Text From Jtextfield (Jframe) To another class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

i put text on a JTextfield and i try to use that text in another class
... i have no error but no result

```
    btnEntrez.addActionListener(new AuthentificationListner());
```

public class AuthentificationListner implements ActionListener{

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Authentification aut = new Authentification();
    String login = aut.txtnom.getText();
    System.out.println("Login :"+login);

}
```

result :
Login : (But no textfield text :/ )

Comment: 2 classes not 1

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You create a new `aut` so `login` is whatever value the text is defaulted to; right?

Comment: i jst doing some exrcices cause I have not developed in java for quite some time
step by step ... so i need jst to display text from jtextfield in another class

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Answer (score 2):

If `Authentification` is a `JFrame`, then `aut.txtnom.getText()` isn't going to return anything (other than what it was initialized with) as the user won't have time to enter anything before you try and grab the value, this is what `JDialog` is for.  See [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.

Swing, like most UI frameworks is event driven, something happens, you respond to it, rather the procedural or linear (which your code seems to be trying to do)

Another approach is to use an observer pattern on `Authentification`, which will notify interested parties that something (they might be interested in) has changed.